# In a multicol with a separating border, set a margin between the border and the content

Tags: multicol, minted

I have a minted code listing, displayed in a multicol environment with a separating border between the columns:
[image: A minted code listing, displayed in a multicol environment with a separating border. The border is too close to some of the content.]

The border is too close to some of the content, like `stracka(1,sg,ka).` and `stracka(3,sg,ka).`. **What's a good way to fix it?**

*test.tex*:

```
RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}


\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Kodlistning}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\inputminted[]{prolog}{someprolog.pl}
\end{multicols}
\label{Blah}
\captionof{listing}{Beskrivande text}

\end{document}
```

*someprolog.pl*:

```
stracka(1,c,sg).
stracka(1,sg,ka).
stracka(1,ka,o).
stracka(1,o,t).

stracka(2,c,sg).
stracka(2,sg,sm).
stracka(2,sm,r).
stracka(2,r,h).

stracka(3,c,sg).
stracka(3,sg,ka).
stracka(3,ka,o).
stracka(3,o,kr).

stracka(4,c,sg).
stracka(4,sg,ka).
stracka(4,ka,o).
stracka(4,o,j).

stracka(5,c,sg).
stracka(5,sg,sm).
stracka(5,sm,r).
stracka(5,r,n).

stracka(6,c,sg).
stracka(6,sg,sm).
stracka(6,sm,r).
stracka(6,r,h).

stracka(7,c,st).
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Something like `\setlength{\columnsep}{5pt}` helps?

Comment: as @karlkoeller says there is a parameter for the column sep (the rule goes down the middle of a gap that wide, but your problem is that the lines are overfull anyway and sticking over their specified margins, so making the gap bigger (and the columns narrower) won't help. You need to decide whether to make the font smaller eg stick \footnotesize somewhere or to allwo line wrapping (I don't know if minted allows that)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ah. But how do I know that they are overfull? Do you conclude it from the PDF output? I couldn't find a related warning (and to double check `latexmk --pdf 2>&1 | grep overfull` was blank) when compiling.

Comment: I didn't run it but they clearly are overfull, the final . is touching the rule:-) minted doesn't usually want to play in my cygwin environment, I'll have  a try.. Also look in the log file which has more information than the terminal output usually. Your grep is just looking at the latter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You don't have to run it, I was simply trying to learn. :-) As in the past, LaTeX has usually complained when something was overfull. I didn't find any overfull warning in the log file either, but I'll remember to check it in the future! I think *minted* might be swallowing the complaint. A side note for when Cygwin isn't enough. A cool thing to do is install Ubuntu in a Virtual Box (with Guest Additions) and use "Seamless mode", the result is that you can mix real Linux windows with Windows ones.

Comment: @kyl yes I could run a VB, but at work I just use X to the linux network anyway, but when I'm at home that's less convenient:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get minted to run but just including it as text shows the same thing:

[image]

You get warnings about this in the log (not in the terminal output)

```
Overfull \hbox (15.33626pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
[]\T1/lmtt/m/n/12 stracka(1,sg,ka).
```

You need to have less columns or a smaller font or allow linebreaking. Increasing the column sep with `\setlength\columnsep{...}` without reducing the number of columns will just make things worse as it will make the columns narrower.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}


\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
%\renewcommand\listingscaption{Kodlistning}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\ttfamily\obeylines\footnot
\input{someprolog.pl}
\end{multicols}
\label{Blah}
\captionof{figure}{Beskrivande text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think *minted* is swallowing the overfull warning. I don't get it in any of stderr/stdout/log-file. But it's clearly the case, I switched to 3 columns instead of 4.